# How can I start android application info screen programmatically?

Tags: android

Is it possible to start the "application info" screen (that is, `Menu` → `Settings` → `Applications` → `Manage Applications` → select any application) from another app?

Comment: Is there a way to open specific app's **DATA USAGE** details info?

Answer (score 84):

In 2.2 and below, there is no public APIs you can access. But you can still start the **InstalledAppDetails** activity just as the **ManageApplications** does. see [**here**](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/settings/ManageApplications.java;h=9cd6e23ce3a0fb2254fdaa2ebde3a7fc9324d4e6;hb=c0a606d2d639c34bb763b73974e04e55f2d2ad8d)

```
 // utility method used to start sub activity
 private void startApplicationDetailsActivity() {
     // Create intent to start new activity
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setClass(this, InstalledAppDetails.class);
     intent.putExtra(APP_PKG_NAME, mCurrentPkgName);
     // start new activity to display extended information
     startActivityForResult(intent, INSTALLED_APP_DETAILS);
 }
```

**Conclusion**: you can start the "application info" screen like this i wrote:

```
private static final String SCHEME = "package";

private static final String APP_PKG_NAME_21 = "com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName";

private static final String APP_PKG_NAME_22 = "pkg";

private static final String APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.settings";

private static final String APP_DETAILS_CLASS_NAME = "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails";

public static void showInstalledAppDetails(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    final int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (apiLevel >= 9) { // above 2.3
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(SCHEME, packageName, null);
        intent.setData(uri);
    } else { // below 2.3
        final String appPkgName = (apiLevel == 8 ? APP_PKG_NAME_22
                : APP_PKG_NAME_21);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName(APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME,
                APP_DETAILS_CLASS_NAME);
        intent.putExtra(appPkgName, packageName);
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! this saved me a lot of time. should the comment "above 2.3" be changed to "2.3 and above"?

Comment: this works perfectly for any installed application. However if i try to open settings of any system application, a blank screen comes up.

Comment: Also we need to add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); in both statements. i.e. if(){...here...} else {...here...}

Comment: Awesome Man!! +100 \m/

Comment: Yes, it's Working .awesome !!

Answer (score 77):

From **API Level 9** (Android 2.3) you can start an Intent with [android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS). Thus:

```
packageName = "your.package.name.here"

try {
    //Open the specific App Info page:
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    startActivity(intent);

} catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e ) {
    //e.printStackTrace();

    //Open the generic Apps page:
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Answer (score 20):

I used Paolo solution in order to open the Application Details Settings in SDK 23+ when the user turned down the permission request in the past and choose the "Don't ask again" option in the permission request system dialog.

But in this case I used the `getPackageName()` method directly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 17):

Old question, improved answer:

```
/**
 * <p>Intent to show an applications details page in (Settings) com.android.settings</p>
 * 
 * @param context       The context associated to the application
 * @param packageName   The package name of the application
 * @return the intent to open the application info screen.
 */
public static Intent newAppDetailsIntent(Context context, String packageName) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        return intent;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
        intent.putExtra("pkg", packageName);
        return intent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
    intent.putExtra("com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName", packageName);
    return intent;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In Android 2.3, you can use `startActivity()` on an [`ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS) `Intent`, with a proper `Uri`, to bring up your app's "manage" screen. However, this is new to Android 2.3 -- I am not aware of a way to do that in previous versions of Android.

Answer (score 6):

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS));
```

will bring you to the settings / application list.
If you want to open one specific application, I think in 2.2 and below there's no way, so you'd need to go a (not necessarily suggested, because inofficial) way:

```
final Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");                
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails"));
i.putExtra(...); // need to figure out the correct extra, probably app package name
startActivity(i);
```

But note that this is not recommended because it's not an official API / intent (filter) and might therefore change in the future.

Comment: I won't recommend the latter. What if a malicious app uses the package: com.android.settings?

Comment: @PaoloRovelli I wrote "not necessarily recommended", but for a different reason. I don't think you can avoid the danger that you mention; if two apps use the same intent (string), then the user will always get a dialog to choose the app to use (which lowers the risk a bit). But also, note that the parameter in the first approach is also nothing else but a string: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS - so that's no protection from a malicious app either if it uses the com.android.settings package name.