# How do I open my applications info page?

Tags: java, android

how do I open my applications info page on Android through my app. I want to open the info page for com.xxx.xxx though I keep failing (The one in settings not the market place one). I am using SDK Min Version 8.

Thanks

Comment: If you are trying this from the emulator, I don't think it will work. This feature will only work on a rea device and thats the only way you can test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to link to your Android market page, try opening a url such as:

```
market://details?id=com.example.admob.lunarlander
```

if that's not what you are trying to do you need to explain a little clearer...

Edit: if you are trying to get to the settings part where the user can uninstall your app for example, I think you want to look at this: [How can I start android application info screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/start-android-application-info-screen)

Comment: I mean I want to open the app info page on the settings part not in the market

Comment: you mean you want to have a button that gets the user to the right screen in this screenshot, but for your application? http://cdn.vikitech.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Android-Application-Management-and-Application-Info.jpg