# how i can start application info screen in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to start manage application (`Settings -> Application -> manage application -> Application info`) screen programmatically. I'm unable to do it. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link, it's the same question afaik: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/start-android-application-info-screen

Comment: Please Go through following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/start-android-application-info-screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/start-android-application-info-screen)

In Android 2.3, you can use startActivity() on an ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS Intent, with a proper Uri, to bring up your app's "manage" screen

or

```
private static final String SCHEME = "package";

private static final String APP_PKG_NAME_21 = "com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName";

private static final String APP_PKG_NAME_22 = "pkg";

private static final String APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.settings";

private static final String APP_DETAILS_CLASS_NAME = "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails";

public static void showInstalledAppDetails(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    final int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (apiLevel >= 9) { // above 2.3
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(SCHEME, packageName, null);
        intent.setData(uri);
    } else { // below 2.3
        final String appPkgName = (apiLevel == 8 ? APP_PKG_NAME_22
                : APP_PKG_NAME_21);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName(APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME,
                APP_DETAILS_CLASS_NAME);
        intent.putExtra(appPkgName, packageName);
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: @ChiragPipaliya If the answer is correct then you should vote the question as answered, giving credit to the person who took his time to provide it to you.

Comment: @ChiragPipaliya By voting up the answer and pressing the accept button.

Comment: Thanks AlexandruAverescu... :)

Answer (score 4):

From **API Level 9** (Android 2.3) you can start an Intent with [android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS). Thus:

```
packageName = "your.package.name.here"

try {
    //Open the specific App Info page:
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    startActivity(intent);

} catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e ) {
    //e.printStackTrace();

    //Open the generic Apps page:
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```