# Invoke Android application info screen

Tags: android

How can i invoke activity info for particular application ??

Sample:
[This is sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5eit38j9zxizkks/Screenshot_2013-12-08-12-04-48.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/start-android-application-info-screen
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157102/how-i-can-start-application-info-screen-in-android

Comment: You should avoid posting links to external code/images. What if that link gets removed? Please, eearn to include an image into a question, it's not difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From api level 9 and above you should be able to achieve what you want with the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
startActivity(i);
```

Where packageName is for example: com.example.myapp