# how to launch android application Manager

Tags: android, android-intent

Does anyone know the package name for Application Manager on android.  I have a method that i want to allow the user to go directly from my app to the application manager:

```
 public void goToApplicationManager(){
        Intent startMain = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings.ManageApplications");

        startActivity(startMain);
    }
```

but that throws an error.. i can just do com.android.settings, and it will take the user to settings but i would like to take them specifically to the application manager.  do i have the wrong package name?

my error:

```
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1382)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at com.eliddell.services_test.ServiceLauncher.goToApplicationManager(ServiceLauncher.java:101)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at com.eliddell.services_test.ServiceLauncher$4.onClick(ServiceLauncher.java:156)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:168)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
10-24 13:36:43.748: E/AndroidRuntime(31133):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: May be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name

Comment: This answer shows how you can open the Application Manager -> Application Info for a particular app. You just need to specify the package name of that app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4772481/1617737

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
startActivity(
 new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS) or [ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add next permission to your manifest:  "android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"