# disable heads up notification for a specific app using adb

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

I know you can disable heads up notification for all apps using :

```
adb shell settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 0
```

and block or unblock notification using :

```
adb shell service call notification 6 s16 \"Package\" i32 uid i32 0/1
```

now how can I disable/enable heads up notification for a specific app Android 6.0

Comment: since you have entered Package and package name is enough to disable notification for an app.

Comment: If you are here, you probably want to be here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53198696/843000 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18455663/843000