# Any way to link to the Android notification settings for my app?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there any way I can launch an intent to get to Android's notification settings screen for my app (pictured below)? Or an easy way I can make a PreferenceScreen item that just leads here on a click?

[image]

Comment: It looks like Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS will get me to the main app info screen, but I'm trying to get one step further into the Notification settings on the app info screen...

Comment: While we're at it @mohamed-hafez, could you explain how you did to anchor this "App settings" entry here? I head that it's done via an intent-filter in the Manifest, but failed to do it. Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel, looks like you already found the answer to your question, but for anyone else interested, the answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28710214/238753).

Comment: how to open app notification category (Default) ? on orio. where we can change sound,vibration and other setting

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The following will work in Android 5.0 (Lollipop) and above:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

//for Android 5-7
intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);

// for Android 8 and above
intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());

startActivity(intent);
```

Notes: This is not officially supported in Android 5-7, but it works just fine. It IS officially supported as of Android 8. This code is not backwards compatible with versions of Android before 5.0.

Comment: @shhp - Thank you for this answer. Also works in N preview. Would you please say in a few words how you found this solution? The farthest I got in this investigation was this log message: `com.android.settings D/SubSettings: Launching fragment com.android.settings.notification.AppNotificationSettings` when clicking the "Notifications" line in app settings. [link2src](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/notification/AppNotificationSettings.java)

Comment: @Dev-iL you get the first step. Then I checked the source code to see what extras should be put in the `intent` :-)

Comment: This is cool, but users should be aware of a few things: 1) This intent relies on internal/hidden code of the `Settings` app, so there's no guarantee that in the future the `Settings` app won't change and no longer use the same String action, component, or Intent extras to open the app specific notification screen. 2) This method is not completely backward compatible. The String action and components used were introduced about 2 years ago. [**See commit here**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/802ddf99f57e316d0fd87c2cfeed5dc3a0cfa8fe)

Comment: @TonyChan Thank you for the reminder. I will add them in the answer.

Comment: Just edited so this will work with Android O, in addition to Android 5-7. Note: this is officially supported in Android O!

Comment: Just a side note: you can also reach the specific notification channel setting, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48854197/878126

Comment: @shhp  how to open apps notification categories on Android Oreo

Comment: @SagarHudge sorry, have no idea for the moment.

Answer (score 108):

I merged the solution of Sergei and Shhp to support all the cases :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
        intent.putExtra("app_package", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("app_uid", context.getApplicationInfo().uid);
    } else {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS and "android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS" string value are same. then why is this?

Comment: `"android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS"` is a literal string because `Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS` is only available from API 26

Answer (score 16):

I've appended Channel Notification Settings for Android 8.0 Oreo API 26 or later. There is a solution from Android 4.4, KitKat.

Usage for Channel notification settings:

```
// PRIMARY_CHANNEL:
goToNotificationSettings(getString(R.string.PRIMARY_CHANNEL), mContext);
// SECONDARY_CHANNEL:
goToNotificationSettings(getString(R.string.SECONDARY_CHANNEL), mContext);
```

Usage for App notification settings:

```
goToNotificationSettings(null, mContext);
```

The method of goToNotificationSettings:

```
public void goToNotificationSettings(String channel, Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        intent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        if (channel != null) {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
            intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, channel);
        } else {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        }
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (channel != null) {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
            intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, channel);
        } else {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        }
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        intent.putExtra("app_package", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("app_uid", context.getApplicationInfo().uid);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS is available from API >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O so it shouldn't be used on N_MR1 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS

Comment: code inside `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1)` will never be executed, in some parts you're correctly using `Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS` but in some others you're using hardcode string `"android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS"`

Answer (score 13):

For lazy men this is the kotlin version of @Helix answer:

```
fun openAppNotificationSettings(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent().apply {
        when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
                action = Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS
                putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.packageName)
            }
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP -> {
                action = "android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS"
                putExtra("app_package", context.packageName)
                putExtra("app_uid", context.applicationInfo.uid)
            }
            else -> {
                action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                data = Uri.parse("package:" + context.packageName)
            }
        }
    }
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle push notification setting from inside the app without starting settings activity?

Comment: Writing a 2023 update in a separate answer...

Answer (score 7):

An updated version written in **Kotlin** that includes all cases described here.

```kotlin
fun showNotificationSettings(context: Context, channelId: String? = null) {
    val notificationSettingsIntent = when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O /*26*/ -> Intent().apply {
            action = when (channelId) {
                null -> Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS
                else -> Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS
            }
            channelId?.let { putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, it) }
            putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.packageName)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P /*28*/) {
                flags += Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            }
        }
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP /*21*/ -> Intent().apply {
            action = Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS
            putExtra("app_package", context.packageName)
            putExtra("app_uid", context.applicationInfo.uid)
        }
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT /*19*/ -> Intent().apply {
            action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
            data = Uri.parse("package:${context.packageName}")
        }
        else -> null
    }
    notificationSettingsIntent?.let(context::startActivity)
}
```

You can use it like this

```kotlin
showNotificationSettings(context)
```

or you can add channel ID to show channel settings

```kotlin
showNotificationSettings(context, channelId = "some_channel_id")
```

Comment: Could you, please, clarify, why you need the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag for android P and newer?

Answer (score 5):

I use this code (kitkat and next versions):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
    intent.putExtra("app_package", getActivity().getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("app_uid", getActivity().getApplicationInfo().uid);
    startActivity(intent);
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I merged the code of some of the answers above and added little edit, I have tested and it working fine on Android KitKat, Lollipop, Marshmallow, Nougat, Oreo and Pie, API level 19 - 28

```
public void goToNotificationSettings(Context context) {

    String packageName = context.getPackageName();

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
            intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, packageName);
            intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", packageName);

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
            intent.putExtra("app_package", packageName);
            intent.putExtra("app_uid", context.getApplicationInfo().uid);

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));

        } else {
            return;
        }

        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log goes here           

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an update to the nice Kotlin version written by @carlol.
In the project I'm using this I have minSdk = 21, so the code can be more succint:

```
private fun openAppNotificationSettings(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent().apply {
        when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
                action = Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS
                putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.packageName)
            }
            else -> {
                action = "android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS"
                putExtra("app_package", context.packageName)
                putExtra("app_uid", context.applicationInfo.uid)
            }
        }
    }
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS` will list all channels of the app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

To open the settings for a single channel, you can use `ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS`:

Where you can change `sound,vibration.etc` settings for individual channel.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.CHANNEL_ID", "ChannelID");
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());
        startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to present a (imho) cleaner version of @Helix answer:

```
fun openNotificationsSettings() {
    val intent = Intent()
    when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> intent.setOpenSettingsForApiLarger25()
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP -> intent.setOpenSettingsForApiBetween21And25()
        else -> intent.setOpenSettingsForApiLess21()
    }
    app.startActivity(intent)
}

private fun Intent.setOpenSettingsForApiLarger25(){
    action = Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS
    putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", app.packageName)
}

private fun Intent.setOpenSettingsForApiBetween21And25(){
    action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
    putExtra("app_package", app.packageName)
    putExtra("app_uid", app.applicationInfo?.uid)
}

private fun Intent.setOpenSettingsForApiLess21(){
    action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
    data = Uri.parse("package:" + app.packageName)
}
```

One can go even further and extract each when branch into a compact class. And create a factory in which `when` would be.

Comment: "And create a factory..." And this is how you make simple code complex.

Comment: @Ridcully well, looking back to answer I would agree 100%. But I won't edit cause it makes a nice irony of overengineering.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void goToNotificationSettings(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromParts(SCHEME, context.getPackageName(), null));
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
            intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
            intent.putExtra("app_package", context.getPackageName());
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
            intent.putExtra("app_package", context.getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra("app_uid", context.getApplicationInfo().uid);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
        } else {
            return;
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: What is the SCHEME constant?

Comment: Looks the branch `else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1)` will be never called

Answer (score 0):

Finally i tested almost all devices and works fine. The code given as follows

```
public void goToPushSettingPage(Context context) {
    try {
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1){
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
            intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE,context.getPackageName());
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
            intent.putExtra(ConstUtil.PUSH_SETTING_APP_PACKAGE,context.getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra(ConstUtil.PUSH_SETTING_APP_UID,context.getApplicationInfo().uid);
        }else{
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(ConstUtil.PUSH_SETTING_URI_PACKAGE+context.getPackageName()));
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log goes here
    }
}
```