# Access application notification settings programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-settings

In an Android app, I have a button that I want to have the functionality of opening the App Notification settings (in Android settings).

[image: Screenshot of Android's notification settings for the Camera application]

I can open the Android settings with this

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

but I want to open directly on my app notification settings

**Alternative**

If there is a way to turn the "Block notifications" on and off programmatically that would be ok too.

Comment: Add a boolean, save it and add settings inside the app.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no public API that will allow you to deep link into your application's notification settings directly.

You can use [`Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS) to deep link to your application's settings, but this will not take you directly to the notifications screen.

[Any way to link to the Android notification settings for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366649/any-way-to-link-to-the-android-notification-settings-for-my-app) has a solution that may work, but since it is not a part of the official API it is not guaranteed to work on all devices or for future versions of Android.

> if there is a way to turn the "Block notificaations" on and off programatically that would be ok too

Absolutely not. Allowing an application to programmatically turn it's notifications on and off defeats the purpose of giving the user control over turning notifications on and off.

Comment: ill use the  Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS then, thanks

Comment: I am using `APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS` to open setting ,how to open sub category?

Answer (score 65):

I know this is an old question, but for those finding it in the future: as of Oreo (API level 26) there is now an official deeplink `Intent` for a specific app's notification settings.

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName())
        .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, MY_CHANNEL_ID);
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

The `EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID` parameter is optional, and according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS), will "highlight that channel." FWIW, as of Android 8.1, I can't see that it makes any difference. If you are adding this parameter, ensure your `Action` is `ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS`.

Comment: how to open app `notification category` (Default) ? on orio. where we can change sound,vibration and other setting.

Comment: In order to open settings of a particular channel use 
new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)

Comment: @DmitryGrushin Oh man, You just saved my life, the settings app would crash if I provide a `EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID` extra with `ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS` action.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how to open app notification category (Default) ? on orio. where we can change sound,vibration and other setting

Comment: Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName())
                .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, "channel_id");
        startActivity(settingsIntent);