# Can't bring the user to Notifications settings

Tags: java, android, xml

So in my app at the moment when the user first loads it up they get a prompt to go to the Notification access menu. If they select yes it redirects to it, if they say no they go just go onto the apps page.

```
private AlertDialog buildNotificationServiceAlertDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("one");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("two");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("no",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    return (alertDialogBuilder.create());
}
```

When I click "yes" it just closes the app and when I press "no" it does what it should. I've tested this on with other apps and my app does appear in the Notification access menu but I can't redirect to it from my own app.

Any one have any ideas why it's not working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add package name in intent to work it.

```
Intent notifIntent = new Intent();
notifIntent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");

//for Android 5-7
notifIntent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
notifIntent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);

// for Android 8
notifIntent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());

startActivity(notifIntent);
```

It will work in Android 5.0 and above.

Comment: This works but I'm looking to get to this menu here http://www.enhancedsmscallerid.com/home/faq/img/notifications-access-3_thumb.png

Comment: I got it now just needed to change "android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS" to
"ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way.

```
 private void enableNotification(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
    if(Build.VERSION.PREVIEW_SDK_INT<=Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
    }else{
    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This caused the app to crash when I start it up

Comment: Check the logcat . Must be a Security exception . Permission related

Comment: For more options for version support i have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366649/any-way-to-link-to-the-android-notification-settings-for-my-app) useful . check this out