# Intent to open the Notification Channel settings from my app

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, notification-channel

What's the Intent that I need to send in order to open the settings of a Notification Channel that I've previously created in my app?
I need to link to it from my app.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To open the notification settings for a single channel, use [`ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName())
    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, yourChannelId);
startActivity(intent);
```

To open the notification settings for the app in general (i.e. to see all channels), use [`ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how to open default notification category?

Comment: any idea please help?

Comment: Also check this one for support older versions than Android O and edge case of Lollipop:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61998544/3101777

Answer (score 21):

Here the snippets for the notification settings as well as the granular channel settings:

```
private void openNotificationSettings() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@RequiresApi(26)
private void openChannelSettings(String channelId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, channelId);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Kotlin code, supporting older versions than Android **O** and edge case of **Lollipop**:

```
fun openAppNotificationSettings(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent().apply {
        when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
                action = Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS
                putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.packageName)
            }
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP -> {
                action = "android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS"
                putExtra("app_package", context.packageName)
                putExtra("app_uid", context.applicationInfo.uid)
            }
            else -> {
                action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                data = Uri.parse("package:" + context.packageName)
            }
        }
    }

    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```