# Notifications Settings activity for all apps in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

OS: Android Oreo
Device: Samsung Galaxy S9

I want the user to land to the activity where he can check for permission of notifications enabled/disabled for all the apps and not just single app.
I've found multiple resources which lands the user to app specific notification settings.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the activity I want the user to start through Intent.[image]

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366649/any-way-to-link-to-the-android-notification-settings-for-my-app

Comment: yes, that is just for a particular app. I want to open activity for all the apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, currently it is **not possible** using official Android API to access Notification Settings of All apps i.e. **`Settings > Apps & notifications > See all <N> apps`** (this path from Pixel API 27) activity is not able to access.

In case of Samsung they might have their own UI customization which is one more step of difficulty to access this Activity.

Comment: Yes... I've been through all the android settings intent actions but no action to land on notification settings for all the apps. It is just possible to land on app specific notification setting.