# How to getSound(), getName() from application NotificationChannel >=Oreo

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, notification-channel

How to get following details from particular application Notification channel

- getSound(); getName(); getId(); getGroup();

I have tried with following code but it returns system default channel details

```
 Uri=playSound ;
 String id = ApplicationClass.getInstance().HighNotificationChannelID;
 NotificationChannel mChannels = new NotificationChannel(id, getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
 playSound = mChannels.getSound();
```

**O/P:-** content://settings/system/notification_sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many searches I found the following way from which you can get all the details.

Following link shows How to Open your app notification channel setting programmatically.

[open app notification setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366649/any-way-to-link-to-the-android-notification-settings-for-my-app/52924036#52924036)

This may help someone.

> Following code will return you all channels of application

```
public static List<NotificationChannel> getNotificationChannels(Context context) {
    if (isNotificationChannelSupported(context)) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager == null) {
            Log.e("", "Notification manager is null");
            return null;
        }
        return notificationManager.getNotificationChannels();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isNotificationChannelSupported(Context context) {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26 && getTargetSdkVersion(context) >= 26;
}

private static int getTargetSdkVersion(Context context) {
    int targetSdk = -1;
    if (context != null) {
        targetSdk = context.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion;
    }
    return targetSdk;
}
```

> Following line will return you sound `Uri` same way you can get name,Id etc.
>   `get(2)` is channel you want to refer to retrieve details you can use 0,1 also

```
Uri soundUri= getNotificationChannels(this).get(2).getSound()
```