# How to enabled floating notification by default with react-native-firebase?

Tags: android, react-native, android-notifications, react-native-firebase

Halo, I have push notification in react-native using react-native-firebase, it's running well on emulator but on some devices **the floating notification, lockscreen notification and sound** disabled by default.

[image: default setting]

how to force enable those setting with app installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt try but first you can check if notifications are disabled by using `NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()`, from support library. The versions below API 19 will return true (notifications are enabled).

Then if notifications disabled, you can warn your user and start notification settings like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32368604/1744538):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");

//for Android 5-7
intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);

// for Android 8 and above
intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thankyou, I forget to check the permission on my rootscreen :D

I use react-native with react-native-firebase, here is the docs:
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/receiving-notifications