# Intent to go to settings page for specific account

Tags: android, android-intent, android-settings

With the following well known code, the user is taken to the overall Android settings page for accounts on the device:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS));
```

[image: sync settings]

Is there an equivalent that takes the user directly to the settings for a specific account (please see below screenshot), provided the account belongs to my application?

[image: specific account sync settings]

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/how-can-i-start-android-application-info-screen-programmatically

Comment: @bigO This takes the user to the app's setting page, not to the account settings for that app.Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> provided the account belongs to my application

That's, I think, you mean you know [account type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html#type) in advance. If so, then following is one possible approach to handle the problem.

First, The app will need `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Then, if you take a look on `onActivityCreated()` of [`AccountSyncSettings`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/accounts/AccountSyncSettings.java) (the activity on your second screenshot), you will notice that it looks for `"account"` key in the launching intent bundle.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No arguments provided when starting intent. ACCOUNT_KEY needed.");
        finish();
        return;
    }
    mAccount = (Account) arguments.getParcelable(ACCOUNT_KEY);
    if (!accountExists(mAccount)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Account provided does not exist: " + mAccount);
        finish();
        return;
    }
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
      Log.v(TAG, "Got account: " + mAccount);
    }
    mUserId.setText(mAccount.name);
    mProviderId.setText(mAccount.type);
}
```

Now, based on that, you can use something as follows to launch that activity for specific account:

```
private static final String ACCOUNT_KEY = "account";
private static final String ACTION_ACCOUNT_SYNC_SETTINGS =
        "android.settings.ACCOUNT_SYNC_SETTINGS";

... // lots of code

Account myAccount = null;
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if ("com.myTLD.myApp".equals(account.type)) {
        myAccount = account;
        break;
    }
}

if (myAccount != null) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(ACCOUNT_KEY, myAccount);

    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_ACCOUNT_SYNC_SETTINGS);
    intent.putExtras(args);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

There are, however, a few things to consider here:

- `AccountSyncSettings` implementation may get changed anytime.
- The above code was not extensively tested. In fact, it was tested only on a single target device (Galaxy S5 with Lollipop).
- `"android.settings.ACCOUNT_SYNC_SETTINGS"` action may not be available on all devices and versions of Android. So, safeguard against possible failures and look for alternative actions.
- Instead of `getAccounts()`, you may actually want to use [`getAccountsByType("com.myTLD.myApp")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccountsByType%28java.lang.String%29) and simply use the first element from the returned array if the target user can not have more than one account on a device.
- If you know [account name](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html#name), you may want to leverage that information to further tune the if clause to match your needs.

Hope this helps.