# How to get Android user to find and change their default home app?

Tags: android

If user selects an app other than my app for default home app, how can I get them to change this? It does not work to just issue intent for default and home category because they might have selected 'always' the other app.  BTW, how would an Android user quickly find which app they selected earlier as their default home?  I would like to send them to settings where the default app is located, but how can I do send them to the right place to find the currently selected default?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the current launcher package name and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/how-can-i-start-android-application-info-screen-programmatically) to send the user to the settings screen where they can delete default values.