# How to uninstall the app from listview in android

Tags: android

Greeting everyone!!
I am creating an android application on it i have to make an option of uninstalling the installed application.

I have listed the installed application using the following code.

Here is my code.

```
 packageManager = getPackageManager();
 List<ApplicationInfo> list = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
 PACKAGENAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
 new LoadApplications().execute();
```

But i don't know how to uninstall the apps by presenting my code on OnClickListener.

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: you can't uninstall directly without root access of device. Only thing you can do is to take user to the installed screen of that app in settings

Comment: tq vivek.How can i do that??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/how-can-i-start-android-application-info-screen-programmatically see this link

Answer (score 0):

```
String packageNameOfAppToUninstall = "org.abc.test"; 
Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:" + packageNameOfAppToUninstall);
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageUri);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Comment: i know this.the problem is i cant able to get the app name from the list vieew

Comment: then, Where is the code of listview? How can you get the solution without showing your code?

Comment: is there any way to get the names of all the installed apps in our phone??

Comment: You have already mentioned in your question that you have already done this.